# Setting onmouseover on a table cell

Tags: javascript, html

In the second (right/bing) table entry, I understand why hovering from the image to the 'bing' string could cause `bingfn()` to be fired.

But the first (left/google) table has the `onmouseover` in the `<td>`, hence I'm expecting that hovering from the image to the text and back will not cause the counter to increase. Why does the counter increase? And is there anything wrong with having a single `<a>` around a combination of items (an `<img>`, a `<br />`, and some text, in this case)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>On Mouse Over in tables</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover="googlefn()">
                    <a href="http://google.com/">
                        <img width="100" src="google.jpg">
                        <br />
                        Google
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p onmouseover="bingfn()">
                        <a href="http://bing.com/">
                            <img width="100" src="bing.jpg"><br />
                            Bing</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="gcountarea">G.count</td>
                <td id="bcountarea">B.count</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script>
            var gcount = 0;
            var bcount = 0;

            function googlefn() {
                document.getElementById("gcountarea").innerHTML = gcount+=1;
            }

            function bingfn() {
                document.getElementById("bcountarea").innerHTML = bcount+=1;
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want, I can make my answer elegant as well, though functional might should be preferred ... and working :)

Comment: @LGSon I'd love that. I haven't checked a "right" answer yet because I see that what you wrote technically answers the question fully while sticking to my messy code, whereas Sukima's answer points out to how it should be done while skipping the crux of the question: how to avoid the unnecessary triggering of events. So an addendum to the question is: suppose the table in question is quite vast. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It increases because when you move mouse over the image/link it fires a new `mouseover`, and because of [event bubbling](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) it counts again.

I updated your script to check which elements the mouse is over before counting and also changed the event from `mouseover` to `mouseenter`, so it doesn't count when the mouse reenters the `td`/`p` from the image/link.

***Updated***

As requested (wished for), I made the script more dynamic, so by adding the attribute `data-counter` to an element, give it a value like `googlecounter` and then use the same value (`googlecounter`) as an id on an element, to which the counter should be written, and voila...:)

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('[data-counter]');
for (i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].hitcounter = 0;      
  els[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e){        
    if(e.target.hitcounter != undefined) {          
      e.target.hitcounter++;
      document.getElementById(e.target.getAttribute('data-counter')).innerHTML = e.target.hitcounter;          
    }        
  });      
}
```

```html
<h3>On Mouse Over in tables</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td" data-counter="googlecounter">
      <a href="http://google.com/">
        <img width="100" src="google.jpg">
        <br />
        Google
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id="p" data-counter="bingcounter">
        <a href="http://bing.com/">
          <img width="100" src="bing.jpg"><br />
          Bing</a></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="googlecounter">G.count</td>
    <td id="bingcounter">B.count</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would break this out into functions and encapsulate the states into a class. For example:

```js
function Counter(identifier) {
  this.count = 0;
  this.identifier = identifier;
  this.el = document.querySelector('.counter.' + identifier);
  this.hoverEl = document.querySelector('[data-counter=' + identifier + ']');
}
Counter.prototype.includesElement = function(el) {
  return this.hoverEl.contains(el);
};
Counter.prototype.mark = function() {
  this.count++;
  return this;
};
Counter.prototype.display = function() {
  this.el.innerHTML = '' + this.count;
  return this;
};

var counters = [
  new Counter('google'),
  new Counter('bing')
];

document.addEventListener('mouseover', function (evt) {
  counters.forEach(function (counter) {
    if (counter.includesElement(evt.target)) {
      counter.mark().display();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>On Mouse Over in tables</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td data-counter="google">
                    <a href="http://google.com/">
                        <img width="100" src="google.jpg">
                        <br />
                        Google
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td data-counter="bing">
                    <p>
                        <a href="http://bing.com/">
                            <img width="100" src="bing.jpg"><br />
                            Bing</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="counter google">G.count</td>
                <td class="counter bing">B.count</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm missing something. I don't see where you referenced the js script from the html file.

Comment: it is added by stack overflow. It is as if it was pasted into a `<script>` tag at the bottom of the HTML

Comment: Ah.. got it. I had tried to put the <script> in the <head>, but that didn't work. I'm guessing because HTML parsing is a one-pass "compilation" and hence the <td counter> and the <td class> must have been encountered before the script runs. Also, your code is very elegant, and I have a sense that this is the way to go. It seems you implicitly approve of having both an <img> and a string inside an <a> anchor, since you also do that. But the triggering continues when the cursor moves from img to the text and back. So that's not of concern? It seems to be wasteful to fire events needlessly.

Comment: Yes, if you place Javascript in the head then the html is not ready at the time the Javascript runs. While at the end the html is available for the Javascript. This is why jQuery has the `ready()` function to defer the javascript till the html is ready. `mouseover` is an event that triggers multiple times. You would have to do some advanced debouncing to prevent that. Or you could look at the `hover` or `mouseenter` events instead.